# What is the performance difference between using StreamBridge and defining MessageChannel bindings using the EnableBinding annotation?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder

This is the current approach suggested in the docs for producers in foreign event driven applications:

```java
@Autowired
StreamBridge streamBridge;
....

bridge.send("binding1" , message);
bridge.send("binding2" , message);
```

The previous approach using `EnableBinding` looked like:

```java
MessageChannel binding1();
MessageChannel binding2();

...
binding1.send(message);
binding2.send(message);
```

My question is if there's any performance overhead and if there's any difference between the two approaches in terms of message throughput or polling?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `@EnableBinding` any more.

If your logic is really based on `MessageChannel`, see if you don't use Spring Cloud Stream wrong way. The `StreamBridge` is not for abusing all the time: better to rely on Spring Integration if logic is based on the `MessageChannel` knowledge.

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/4.0.0-M3/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_sending_arbitrary_data_to_an_output_e_g_foreign_event_driven_sources